# storybook error declaration or statement expected

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

Does anyone know how can I fix this issues?

I tried delete node_modules and then install it back but still getting this error

```
C:/Users/nnguy128/Desktop/mvw-engine-enhanced-voa-reservation-ui/node_modules/@storybook/react/dist/ts3.9/client/preview/types-6-0.d.ts
TypeScript error in C:/Users/nnguy128/Desktop/mvw-engine-enhanced-voa-reservation-ui/node_modules/@storybook/react/dist/ts3.9/client/preview/types-6-0.d.ts(4,1):
Declaration or statement expected.  TS1128

    2 | import { Args, ComponentAnnotations, StoryAnnotations, AnnotatedStoryFn } from '@storybook/csf';
    3 | import { StoryFnReactReturnType } from './types';
  > 4 | export type { Args, ArgTypes, Parameters, StoryContext } from '@storybook/csf';
      | ^
```

Comment: Need more context maybe  >- Context: What led to the error? What was the code trying to do when it failed?
>- The error itself: What exactly failed?

Comment: When I run `npm start` it got this error

Comment: Anyone have idea how can I fix this error?